# Searching for an odometer / mileage counter / rounded rectangle numbers font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am in need of a font with numbers that look like this:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know of a font with numbers like these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a [post on Typophile](http://typophile.com/node/85125) looking for the same thing:

> I am trying to identify the font used on many car odometers. The closest I've come is eurostile and microgramma but neither match the seven and the corners are more angular. Any help would be appreciated.

The two fonts that the author lists are great candidates if you're not as picky:

[image: Eurostile LT Pro Roman font sample]

[image: Microgamma D Medium Extended font sample]

Neither are free. There are a few non-commercial fonts that share that "rounded rectangle" look, but I think they all could use some work:

[image: Oloron font sample]

[image: Pirulen Rg Font sample]

[image: Rational Integer font sample]

Answer (score 4):

A great option, in my opinion, would be Mark van Bronkhorst's [**ITC Conduit® Medium**](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-conduit/medium):

[image]

[**Bitsumishi Pro v2**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/cheapprofonts/bitsumishi-pro-v2/) could also work:

[image]

If you are loking for a free alternative, something like [**Highway Gothic**](http://www.dafont.com/highway-gothic.font?text=123456789) or [**Mouse Deco**](http://www.dafont.com/mouse-deco.font?fpp=50&text=123456789) are not too far from my mental image of a speedometer / mileage counter:

[image]